# I'm getting a NullPointerException when accessing static constraints

Tags: grails, groovy

The code

```
${personRequest.constraints.requestStatus.inList}
```

in my gsp file throws a `NullPointerException`, but `new PersonRequest().constraints..` works. Why? Isn't `constraints` static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from [here](http://markmail.org/message/3rx6u2e7bg5dz5n5#query:nullpointerexception%20constraints%20gsp%20grails%20inlist+page:1+mid:uru4kl2yq5xg4nio+state:results) (grails-user mailing list)

> but why accesing to static fields
>   doesnt work?
>
> Because the "constraints" static field
>   is a closure property. It has   no
>   sub-properties relating to the
>   constraints.
>
> Grails evaluates this closure using a
>   constraint builder which   monitors
>   "calls" to methods that don't exist,
>   i.e. the property names   you use:
>
> ```
> type( inList: [xxxxx])
> ```
>
> ...causes a method call to "type" with
>   a Map parameter containing   "inList"
>   ==> some value.
>
> From this info, Grails builds up a
>   list of all the constraints
>   available and binds them to future
>   instances of the domain class.
>
> So, when you access User.constraints
>   statically, you are getting a
>   Closure.
>
> We -could- look at replacing the value
>   of the static constraints   property
>   at runtime after evaluating the
>   Closure it is initialized   with.
>   However this could be a bit "too much"
>   magic. What do people   think?
>
> FYI it's like this now because until
>   0.4 (if I recall) constraints   weren't static, and in 0.4 they can
>   still be non-static. Only in 0.5
>   will we throw an exception/ignore
>   non-static constraints.